# PrimeFaces uploadFile, trying to upload multiple files and stopping at one

Tags: jsf, primefaces

So basically, I have a fileUploader that I want to do multiple files at a time.  When I click upload with 2 or more files, it runs the event handler once, and then stops, not running it again for the rest of the files, even though it shows them in queue on the page.

```
        <h:panelGroup>                               
            <h:panelGrid columns="3" >
                <h:outputText value="Attach Files:"/>
                <p:fileUpload allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(doc|docx|xls|xlsx|pdf)$/" mode="advanced" multiple="true" sizeLimit="30000000" auto="true" fileUploadListener="#{requestPart.handleFileUpload}" update="messages"/>
                <p:messages id="mgs" showDetail="true"/> 
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:panelGroup>
```

My event handler code is as follows

```
private List<UploadedFile> uploadedFileList = new ArrayList<UploadedFile>();

public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) throws NotSupportedException, SystemException, SQLException
{

    System.out.println("Uploading Request Part files....");
    UploadedFile file = event.getFile();
    uploadedFileList.add(file);
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("File attached successfully.", file.getFileName() + " is uploaded.");  
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);  

}
```

Could anyone point me in the write direction?  As far as I know, the event is just one file at a time and never a list?

Answer (score 1):

Which version of PF?
I had similar problem with PF 5.0.
Try with this:

```
    public static synchronized void addToList{
    uploadedFileList.add(file);
    }
```

Comment: I'm using 3.5.  They actually changed the requirements on me so I no longer need to do this but I'll keep it marked.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

*My solution is:*

`sequential="true"`  add in your `fileUpload` and your bean

```
 private List<UploadedFile> archImagen;

 public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
        archImagen.add( event.getFile()); 
}
```